# How to override generic method in scala and call it with reflection

Tags: scala, generics

Here is my parent class

```scala
sealed trait Conf
sealed case class EmptyConf(value:String) extends Conf

abstract class EntryPoint() {
  def create[C <: Conf](conf: C): Definition
}
```

Here is the child

```scala
class TestEntryPoint extends EntryPoint {
  override def create(conf: EmptyConf): Definition = ???
}
```

Compiler says:

```
class TestEntryPoint needs to be abstract, 
since method create in class EntryPoint of type [C <: Conf](conf: C)Definition 
is not defined
```

What do I do wrong?

UPD:
I tried

```
abstract class EntryPoint[C <: Conf]() {
  def create(conf: C): Definition
}

class TestEntryPoint extends EntryPoint[EmptyConf] {
  override def create(conf: EmptyConf): Definition = ???
}
```

Then I have troubles instantiating it using reflection.

```
private def instantiate[P <: EntryPoint[_]](entryPointClass: Class[P],
                                                   conf: Conf): Definition = {
    entryPointClass.getConstructor()
      .newInstance()
      .create(conf)
  }
```

It won't compile since `create` expects subclass of `Conf`. How can I get it in runtime?

UPD:
It works, thank you.
Just add some bruteforce

```
entryPointClass.getDeclaredMethods
      .find(_.getName == "create")
      .map(_.invoke(instance, conf))
      .map(_.asInstanceOf[Definition])
      .getOrElse(throw DefinitionInstantiationException(
        s"Can't instantiate ${entryPointClass.getName} " +
          s"using configuration ${conf.getClass.getName}",
        new RuntimeException))
```

Not type-save though...

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using reflection? Seems like a typeclass would be a much better way to go.

Comment: Hi Tim, user implements EntryPoint and then submits jar to my service. I have to instantiate his EntryPoint implementation in Runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is what you want

```
abstract class EntryPoint[C <: Conf]() {
  def create(conf: C): Definition
}

class TestEntryPoint extends EntryPoint[EmptyConf] {
  override def create(conf: EmptyConf): Definition = ???
}
```

Comment: Hi bottaio, thanks for your response! It tried it then I have problems with instantiating it using reflection. Let me update the question